# Why browsers crop java applet?

Tags: java, html, applet, repaint

I created a Java applet supposed to be used in an applet as applets should.

For some reason, all browsers (chrome, firefox, IE) cut it.

[image: image of Java applet]

I tried using the `repaint()` and `invalidate()` methods. I didn't help...

But, interestingly, when I scroll the browser up or down (even a tiny scroll), it immediately fixes. Also, when I use `showOptionDialog(Component, String)` method, if fixes after the user clicks the OK button on the dialog. It fixes only when the component inputted is the applet itself.

I don't understand why it crops, or how to fix it.

The HTML calling the applet it is very simple. Here is an example of a short piece of HTML code which causes the problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>nispahit</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <center>
            <APPLET CODE="Applet/AppletMain.class" archive="nnis.jar, log4j-1.2.16.jar" WIDTH=800 HEIGHT=600> 
                <param name="userName" value="http://www.nispahit.com/images/shalom.jpg"> 
                <param name="ColorsContrast" value="241026555"/>
                <param name="param2" value="14"> 
                <param name="param3" value="2"> 
                <param name="param3" value="2"> 
            </APPLET>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

A solution or workaround will help very much. Any insight would also be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cropping happens outside of the applet. There is some block element around the applet (usually a `<div>`) which is too small to contain the whole applet.

Try to add a `div` with a red background around the applet so you can see quickly which part is rendered by the browser and which comes from the applet.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't think it's the html problem. I added an example html - with this html the cropping happens. Also, when I scroll with the mouse or when there is a message box, it fixes itself, so I think it is not the html's problem (I could be wrong though...)

Comment: What happens when you set the width to `1000`? Also see my edits.

Comment: Actually, when I changed the width to 1000 it's not cut off. Still, when I scroll the mouse up or down - the size of the applet changes. I accepted your answer, because it was good enough for me, but if someone has an idea as to why scrolling the mouse would change the size of the applet (only once - then it stays in the same size) - I would be glad to hear... @Aaron, thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to use color to see whether the applet changes or the html around it?